# Scheduling Android Service to Run & Restart if Closed

Tags: android, service, background, restart, schedule

I'm trying to implement an App that will perform a periodic sync w/ server, lets say ever 30 min. I have been successfully able to implement this using a Receiver & Service triggered via AlarmManager, however the downside is that if the App is closed through TaskMgr the alarm dies with it.

I understand that this is expected behavior for Android OS, however I noticed that some Apps like Facebook have a service that starts back up after a short timeout even if the Facebook App was closed in TaskMgr. I monitored this and see the service disappear and re-start after about a minute or so. There's a number of Apps that behave in similar fashion (Twitter, Dictionary, ReadItLater, etc)

I would like to reproduce this behavior. This way even if the user closes my App in TaskMgr by mistake they can still have periodic sync run in the background.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an inbound process associated with the service if it needs to be restarted even after cloasing using task killers.YOu can achieve this by displaying an ongoing notification at notification area as long as service exists and by launching service via startForeground()

http://www.androiddiscuss.com/1-android-discuss/91804.html
please check the link

Comment: this doesn't help. task killers can kill a running service even when paired with a notification

Comment: Well I'm trying to find out how Apps like Facebook restart their own service. Even after you kill it w/ task mgr it comes back after a minute or so. Alarm Manager doesn't seem to work because all Alarms get killed by task mgr as well - there must be another way..